# Can't add a text file to an empty content project?

Tags: visual-studio, text-files

How do i add a textfile to an empty content project? The only options i have are Bitmap File, XML File, Effect File and Sprite Font

Also, if i simply change the extension of the file to .txt, it doesn't show up.

Comment: empty content project.... i think HusseinX is right, except, my program doesn't seem to recognize that the textfile is there now for some reason...

Comment: I can't find the project type "empty content project", I only find "Blank solution", or "Empty ??? Project" of several kind of languages...

Comment: HusseinX helped, in some ways. For some reason if i dump the textfiles in the bin folder of the project, everything works as intended.

Comment: As for the project type, i think you need the XNA package to be able to see it maybe? Or perhaps visual studio 2010 professional. I'm not sure why you aren't able to see it... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create that file and add it as existing item